# Proof for Arrhenius equation

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

The [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation) states that:

$$k=A\mathrm e^{\frac{-E_\mathrm a}{R T}}$$

What is the mathematical proof for this equation?

Comment: Chemistry doesn't work like that. It is not about mathematical proofs at all. When the Arrhenius equation came about, it was an empirical observation. Sure, it is compatible with (read: can be kinda explained by) certain models. Does that constitute a mathematical proof? As for me, not really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In science, theories, hypothesis and particular mathematical models cannot be proven to be right.

It is the principal limitation. They can be proven right only formally as mathematical construct, proving consistency. In relation to reality, there can be just confirmation or refutation of their agreement with experimental data.

The [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation) is based on the model that supposes:

There is a frequency A of geometrically  favourable molecular collisions, that might lead to their reaction. As simplification, it is  implied A does not depend on T. But we know it does, as molecules move faster at higher T.

The exponential factor is based on the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution), predicting the probability molecules would have enough thermal energy to pass the energy barrier - the reaction activation energy.

The confirmation can be done by measuring dependency of reaction kinetics and equilibrium constants on temperature. The latter follows  [van't Hoff equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation),  that is derived from Arrhenius equation, applying it to both forward and reversed reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not in any way a mathematical proof, a theoretical rationale for the general form of the empirical Arrhenius relationship is provided by transition state theory.

The equation that results from transition state theory is $$k=\frac{\kappa k_BT}{h}e^{\frac{\Delta S^\ddagger}{R}}e^{\frac{-\Delta H^\ddagger}{RT}}$$
where the $^\ddagger$ symbol represents properties of the transition state of the reaction, and $\kappa$ is a constant specific to the given reaction (related to, but not the same as the Arrhenius prefactor).

I've deliberately split the two exponential terms, since the second is similar (though not exactly equal) to the exponential term in the Arrhenius equation. The activation energy is a function of the enthalpy change of the transition state, but isn't exactly the same.

The first exponential shows that the Arrhenius pre-factor is a function of the entropy change of the transition state, but the pre-exponential terms explicitly include the temperature-dependence, which is ignored in the Arrhenius equation.